# Why on Chart control the MouseWheel event never called ? And also the AxisViewChanged never called?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have on form1 designer a windows forms chart control.
In form1 constructor i added:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
chart1.MouseWheel += chart1_MouseWheel;
```

Then i have the MouseWheel event:

```
void chart1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hi");
        }
```

And in the designer i also added the event AxisViewChanged:

```
private void chart1_AxisViewChanged(object sender, ViewEventArgs e)
        {
            paintToCalaculate = true;
            chart1.Invalidate();
        }
```

But using a breakpoint in the MouseWheel event or on the AxisViewChanged event it's never get and stop there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mousewheel event not firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782763/mousewheel-event-not-firing)

Comment: This is strange but you need to put the __Focus__ onto the Chart __explicity__. When the zoom works the AxisViewChanged will work, too.. You can [simplify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787050/enabling-mouse-wheel-zooming-in-a-microsoft-chart-control) the linked solution, though..