# Is it OK to set state within Event Raising methods?

Tags: c#, event-handling

I ran across this pattern in the code of a library I'm using. It sets state within the event raising method, but only if the event is not null.

```
protected virtual void OnMyEvent(EventArgs e)
{
  if(MyEvent != null)
  {
     EnsureChildControls(); 
     MyEvent(this,e);
  }
}
```

Which means that the state is not set when overriding the method:

```
protected override void OnMyEvent(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnMyEvent(e);
   Debug.Assert( /* Child controls ensured */); // This fails
}
```

but is only set when handling the event:

```
foo.MyEvent += (o, args) => Debug.Assert(/* Child controls ensured */); // This passes
```

Setting state within the `if(MyEvent != null)` seems like bad form, but I've checked the [Event Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229011.aspx) and it doesn't mention this.

Do you think this code is incorrect? If so, why? (Reference to design guidelines would be helpful).

Edit for Context:

It's a Control, I'm trying to create subclass of it, and the state that it's setting is calling `EnsureChildControls()` conditionally based upon there being an event handler. I can call `EnsureChildControls()` myself, but I consider that something of a hack.

Comment: You won't find any guidelines for this, because having some distinct states during event handling is not a normal occurrence. I suspect it is used in this case to detect re-entrancy, but then event handling code might be rather tightly coupled with the class that publishes events.

Comment: Checking event for null is a best practice in case there is no event handler. Can you clarify the context here... to me it kinda makes sense. If nothing is executing, then the state shouldn't change, right?

Comment: Does 'child controls ensured' become false when the event handler (MyEvent) finishes executing? Because if it does, then your assertion failing is correct. You're checking it after the handler is called. If you want to override OnMyEvent(), don't call the base - just rewrite it completely in your subclass. Make it do exactly what the base version does, plus whatever extra stuff you want the subclass to do.

Comment: @Charles: No, it's always true after EnsureChildControls is called. Your solution fixes the problem for me, but not for anyone else using the library. Also, I had to use Reflector to figure out what the code was doing. The fact that I had to jump through so many hoops makes me feel like the library is somehow "broken".

Comment: Oh, in that case the answer I just wrote can be disregarded. But now I'm not sure I understand the question. It seems like you're unhappy that it's working as designed. If you call OnMyEvent() when there is no event handler assigned, regardless of whether you're in the base class or the subclass, then (according to the original developer), EnsureChildControls() shouldn't be called.

Comment: I think I understand my problem. I've been assuming that overriding OnMyEvent is the preferred way of handling events within the subclass. I'm not sure where I picked up this rule of thumb, but I guess I should handle the event regardless of whether it's a "is a" or a "has a" relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer provides an MSDN quote that answers my question:

[When should you override OnEvent as opposed to subscribing to the event when inheritting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159317/when-should-you-override-onevent-as-opposed-to-subscribing-to-the-event-when-inhe/159334#159334)

> The protected OnEventName method also
>   allows derived classes to override the
>   event without attaching a delegate to
>   it. A derived class must always call
>   the OnEventName method of the base
>   class to ensure that registered
>   delegates receive the event.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you'll find any guidelines on something like this. Guidelines are typically for extremely common occurrences (which I wouldn't consider this).

Regarding the practice itself: I don't see any problem with doing it this way.

For what it's worth, you can avoid `if(MyEvent != null)` if you use this:

```
// initialize with empty delegate so MyEvent will never == null
public event MyEventHandler MyEvent = delegate {};
```

Comment: Keen - that initialization is a nifty little tip to keep in the back of my head.