# how to catch TableNewRow Event of DataTable while loading data

Tags: c#, events, datatable

I want to catch the `TableNewRow` event everytime when an adapter adds a new row to a DataTable.

Are there any ways to catch the NewRow event of a DataTable?

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM t_table";
command.CommandText = sql;
adapter.CommandText = command;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dt);
```

i have tried this code below but it doesnt work..

```
dt.TableNewRow += new DataTableNewRowEventHandler(dt_TableNewRow); 
private void dt_TableNewRow(object sender, DataTableNewRowEventArgs e)
{
       MessageBox.Show("Event Raised...");
}
```

Comment: You need to override this event. Implement the handler as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/160041/23199)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TableNewRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.tablenewrow.aspx) event.

**EDIT:**

As said **[p.cambell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23199/p-campbell)**, you should implement the handler as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159317/when-should-you-override-onevent-as-opposed-to-subscribing-to-the-event-when-inh/160041#160041).

Comment: This event is fired before the invoked NewRow() method

Comment: Implement the handler as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/160041/23199)