# Why style is not applied when I'm removing StartupUri in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I want to apply a default style for all the `Button`s in a WPF app. This *test* app has two `Window`s, both defining the same UI showing bellow.

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
     <Button Content="Red Button Style" />
     <Button Content="Red Button Style" />
     <Button Content="Red Button Style" />
     <Button Content="Red Button Style" />
</StackPanel>
```

So I've defined the global style in `App.xaml`

```xml
<Application x:Class="GlobalStyles.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GlobalStyles">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Height"
                    Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth"
                    Value="180" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize"
                    Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                    Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Padding"
                    Value="8 0" />
            <Setter Property="Margin"
                    Value="4" />
            <Setter Property="Cursor"
                    Value="Hand" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="DarkRed" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="OrangeRed" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and as you've noticed I removed the `StartupUri` property of `Application` since I'm creating both windows at `OnStartUp()`.

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
      protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
      {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            new MainWindow().Show();
            new SecondaryWindow().Show();
      }
```

### The Problem

The styles **are not** applying at runtime (but they do on the designer). Now if I place the `StartUpUri` property inside `App.xaml` then it works.

What's the deal here?

### Edit

If the `base.OnStartup(e)` call is removed from `OnStartup()`, then it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your windows in the Startup handler.

```
private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    new MainWindow().Show();
    new SecondaryWindow().Show();
}
```

Comment: I upvoted because it's a solution, though it does not answer the question. Why that works and `OnStartup()` doesn't?

Comment: Fair point. I agree that this is a bizarre/buggy behavior. If I were to speculate the framework is setup such that if there is no handler defined for Startup it bypasses the code that sets style, etc.